# How to specify those documents from Fire Store to get fetched into a particular Users RecyclerView activity?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXBFb.png)How to specify those documents from Fire Store to get fetched into a particular Users RecyclerView activity?
i have a list of documents in fireStore from multiple users and now i want to fetch those documents in recyclerView.
My problem is how to specify the documents written by a single user having same userID's to get fetched in the users recyclerview.

```
Query query = FStore.collection("Grievances For College");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<StatusAdapter> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<StatusAdapter>()
            .setQuery(query, StatusAdapter.class)
            .build();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot as indicate the exact documents you want to get.

Comment: @AlexMamo check it out!

Comment: Please also indicate the exact documents you want to get.

Comment: @PzdMubasher by looking at your `Grievances for college` collection, there is no userID field that could be used to connect a certain document with a specific user. You would need such a field to fetch this data in the `recyclerView` based on the userID. If it’s not the case, can you also add a screenshot of your `users` collections?